# Bengali Joint letters in Kalpurush font in java messed up

Tags: java, image, text, converters

I have written a program (collecting from various sources, I am a beginner) in Java that takes a text(bengali) written in a .txt file and converts it to a .bmp image using the drawString function. The code is :

```js
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class TextToImageDemo
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String sampleText = "আমার",s="নাম";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        for (int u=1;u<=9;u++)
            {
                
                try
                    {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\Java\\bengtext\\f2-0"+u+".txt")),"UTF-8"));
                        
                        while ((sampleText = br.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                System.out.println(sampleText);
                                s=sampleText;
                            }
                    }
                catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                finally
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                if (br != null)br.close();
                            }
                        catch (IOException ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                
                
                 //Image file name
                 String fileName = "Image";
                 
                 //create a File Object
                 File newFile= new File("./" + fileName + ".jpeg");
                 
                 //create the font you wish to use
                 Font font = new Font(/*Lohit Bengali*/"Kalpurush", Font.PLAIN, 50);
                 
                 //create the FontRenderContext object which helps us to measure the text
                 FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
                 
                 //create a BufferedImage object
                 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(2000, 200,   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                 
                 //calling createGraphics() to get the Graphics2D
                 Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                 System.out.println(s);
                 //set color and other parameters
                 g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                 g.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 200);
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.setFont(font);
                 FontMetrics fm=g.getFontMetrics();
                 Rectangle r=new Rectangle(fm.getStringBounds(s, g).getBounds());
                 String d=s.substring(1,s.length());
                 g.drawString(d, image.getWidth()/2-r.width/2, image.getHeight()/2+r.height/2);     
                 //releasing resources
                 g.dispose();
                 
                 try
                     {
                         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Java\\bengtext\\f2-0"+u+".bmp");
                         ImageIO.write(image,"bmp",fos);
                         fos.close();
                     }
                 catch(Exception ex)
                     {
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                     }
            }  
    }
}
```

My main problem lies in the fact that a text like

> দ্বিতীয়তা , একাগ্রতা , " জ্ঞান আহরনের একটি মাত্র উপায়

is formed like

[image: The problem with র's]

How can this be solved?

Edit:

On checking all the 263 fonts available , I found only 6 of them were able to display bengali somewhat correctly. But in everyone of them the problem with the joint words lie as shown in the above picture. So question is : What is the exact problem happening here? Is JAVA not being able to read the joint words correctly, or is it not being able to draw them correctly ?

And secondly , how to make java draw the joint words correctly?

Comment: I am not familiar with the script, but it looks like an other font was taken: **font substitution**. This can happen in java, but is more likely in the operation system. (Also it could be a font variation like plain/light/medium or even **size**.) You could list all fonts using GraphicsEnvironment, get their name, maybe filter by `Font.canDisplay`. If the font is delivered with the app, one needs `registerFont`.

Comment: "Kalpurush" doesnt exist in your system: so what do you want to do about it?

Comment: @gpasch kalpurursh does exist I think

Comment: @gpasch kalpurushdoes exist I think. Because it was the only Bengali font that my computer was able to read .(not perfectly though). I doldidnot do anything about kalpurush. Just set the font name in the code , itworked

Comment: did you solve your problem then? the only way to know is to list all the fonts - GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] gf=ge.getAllFonts();
String[] gfn=ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
 - its unclear what you seek

Comment: @gpasch :That was a wonderful technique. But unfortunately, the result was this: I found that of the total 263 fonts available, only 6 were able to display Bengali. However in each of them, the same problem lies, the problem with the joint words being wrongly displayed.  I have modified my question to make it more clear

Comment: @gpasch :And please upvote if you feel my question was research oriented.

Comment: have you get any solution

Comment: @MahbuburRahmanKhan Had to make do with the six fonts...

Comment: @Qwerty please give me a help...what is six fonts actually...